# How can I align a text in one line for therm bluetooth printer in Ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework, printing, receipt

I have the plugin that receives and prints the data to the thermal BT printer but I want to format the data so that the output looks nice on the receipt.

Here is the Unicode commands for formatting strings

```js
//commands based on https://github.com/humbertopiaia/escpos-commands-js/blob/master/src/commands.js
//all the commands below may vary by printer, check the manual
export const commands = {
  LF: '\x0a',
  ESC: '\x1b',
  FS: '\x1c',
  GS: '\x1d',
  US: '\x1f',
  FF: '\x0c',
  DLE: '\x10',
  DC1: '\x11',
  DC4: '\x14',
  EOT: '\x04',
  NUL: '\x00',
  EOL: '\n',
  HORIZONTAL_LINE: {
    HR_58MM: '================================',
    HR2_58MM: '********************************'
  },
  FEED_CONTROL_SEQUENCES: {
    CTL_LF: '\x0a', // Print and line feed
    CTL_FF: '\x0c', // Form feed
    CTL_CR: '\x0d', // Carriage return
    CTL_HT: '\x09', // Horizontal tab
    CTL_VT: '\x0b', // Vertical tab
  },
  LINE_SPACING: {
    LS_DEFAULT: '\x1b\x32',
    LS_SET: '\x1b\x33'
  },
  HARDWARE: {
    HW_INIT: '\x1b\x40', // Clear data in buffer and reset modes
    HW_SELECT: '\x1b\x3d\x01', // Printer select
    HW_RESET: '\x1b\x3f\x0a\x00', // Reset printer hardware
  },
  CASH_DRAWER: {
    CD_KICK_2: '\x1b\x70\x00', // Sends a pulse to pin 2 []
    CD_KICK_5: '\x1b\x70\x01', // Sends a pulse to pin 5 []
  },
  MARGINS: {
    BOTTOM: '\x1b\x4f', // Fix bottom size
    LEFT: '\x1b\x6c', // Fix left size
    RIGHT: '\x1b\x51', // Fix right size
  },
  PAPER: {
    PAPER_FULL_CUT: '\x1d\x56\x00', // Full cut paper
    PAPER_PART_CUT: '\x1d\x56\x01', // Partial cut paper
    PAPER_CUT_A: '\x1d\x56\x41', // Partial cut paper
    PAPER_CUT_B: '\x1d\x56\x42', // Partial cut paper
  },
  TEXT_FORMAT: {
    TXT_NORMAL: '\x1b\x21\x00', // Normal text
    TXT_2HEIGHT: '\x1b\x21\x10', // Double height text
    TXT_2WIDTH: '\x1b\x21\x20', // Double width text
    TXT_4SQUARE: '\x1b\x21\x30', // Double width & height text
    TXT_CUSTOM_SIZE: function (width, height) { // other sizes
      var widthDec = (width - 1) * 16;
      var heightDec = height - 1;
      var sizeDec = widthDec + heightDec;
      return '\x1d\x21' + String.fromCharCode(sizeDec);
    },

    TXT_HEIGHT: {
      1: '\x00',
      2: '\x01',
      3: '\x02',
      4: '\x03',
      5: '\x04',
      6: '\x05',
      7: '\x06',
      8: '\x07'
    },
    TXT_WIDTH: {
      1: '\x00',
      2: '\x10',
      3: '\x20',
      4: '\x30',
      5: '\x40',
      6: '\x50',
      7: '\x60',
      8: '\x70'
    },

    TXT_UNDERL_OFF: '\x1b\x2d\x00', // Underline font OFF
    TXT_UNDERL_ON: '\x1b\x2d\x01', // Underline font 1-dot ON
    TXT_UNDERL2_ON: '\x1b\x2d\x02', // Underline font 2-dot ON
    TXT_BOLD_OFF: '\x1b\x45\x00', // Bold font OFF
    TXT_BOLD_ON: '\x1b\x45\x01', // Bold font ON
    TXT_ITALIC_OFF: '\x1b\x35', // Italic font ON
    TXT_ITALIC_ON: '\x1b\x34', // Italic font ON
    TXT_FONT_A: '\x1b\x4d\x00', // Font type A
    TXT_FONT_B: '\x1b\x4d\x01', // Font type B
    TXT_FONT_C: '\x1b\x4d\x02', // Font type C
    TXT_ALIGN_LT: '\x1b\x61\x00', // Left justification
    TXT_ALIGN_CT: '\x1b\x61\x01', // Centering
    TXT_ALIGN_RT: '\x1b\x61\x02', // Right justification
  }
}
```

I have imported this in Ionic home.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController, LoadingController, NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PrinterProvider } from './../../providers/printer/printer';
import { commands } from './../../providers/printer/printer-commands';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  inputData:any = {};
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private printer: PrinterProvider, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private loadCtrl: LoadingController, private toastCtrl: ToastController) {}

  showToast(data) { 
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      duration: 3000,
      message: data,
      position: 'bottom'
    });
    toast.present();
  }

  noSpecialChars(string) {
    var translate = {
        "à": "a",
        "á": "a",
        "â": "a",
        "ã": "a",
        "ä": "a",
        "å": "a",
        "æ": "a",
        "ç": "c",
        "è": "e",
        "é": "e",
        "ê": "e",
        "ë": "e",
        "ì": "i",
        "í": "i",
        "î": "i",
        "ï": "i",
        "ð": "d",
        "ñ": "n",
        "ò": "o",
        "ó": "o",
        "ô": "o",
        "õ": "o",
        "ö": "o",
        "ø": "o",
        "ù": "u",
        "ú": "u",
        "û": "u",
        "ü": "u",
        "ý": "y",
        "þ": "b",
        "ÿ": "y",
        "ŕ": "r",
        "À": "A",
        "Á": "A",
        "Â": "A",
        "Ã": "A",
        "Ä": "A",
        "Å": "A",
        "Æ": "A",
        "Ç": "C",
        "È": "E",
        "É": "E",
        "Ê": "E",
        "Ë": "E",
        "Ì": "I",
        "Í": "I",
        "Î": "I",
        "Ï": "I",
        "Ð": "D",
        "Ñ": "N",
        "Ò": "O",
        "Ó": "O",
        "Ô": "O",
        "Õ": "O",
        "Ö": "O",
        "Ø": "O",
        "Ù": "U",
        "Ú": "U",
        "Û": "U",
        "Ü": "U",
        "Ý": "Y",
        "Þ": "B",
        "Ÿ": "Y",
        "Ŕ": "R"
      },
      translate_re = /[àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûýýþÿŕŕÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÝÝÞŸŔŔ]/gim;
    return (string.replace(translate_re, function (match) {
      return translate[match];
    }));
  }

  print(device, data) {
    console.log('Device mac: ', device);
    console.log('Data: ', data);
    let load = this.loadCtrl.create({
      content: 'Printing...'
    }); 
    load.present();
    this.printer.connectBluetooth(device).subscribe(status => {
        console.log(status);
        this.printer.printData(this.noSpecialChars(data))
          .then(printStatus => {
            console.log(printStatus);
            let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: 'Successful print!',
              buttons: ['Ok']
            });
            load.dismiss();
            alert.present();
            this.printer.disconnectBluetooth();
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: 'There was an error printing, please try again!',
              buttons: ['Ok']
            });
            load.dismiss();
            alert.present();
            this.printer.disconnectBluetooth();
          });
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'There was an error connecting to the printer, please try again!',
          buttons: ['Ok']
        });
        load.dismiss();
        alert.present();
      });
  }

  prepareToPrint(data) {
    let title = "Receipt";
    let revenue = 1000;
    let company = "Company name";
    
  let receipt = '';    
  receipt += commands.HARDWARE.HW_INIT;
      receipt += commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_4SQUARE;
      receipt += commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_ALIGN_CT;
      receipt += title.toUpperCase()
      receipt += commands.EOL;
      receipt += commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_NORMAL;
      receipt += commands.HORIZONTAL_LINE.HR_58MM;
      receipt += commands.EOL;
      receipt += commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_4SQUARE;
      receipt += commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_ALIGN_CT;
      receipt += company.toUpperCase()
      receipt += commands.EOL;
      receipt += commands.HORIZONTAL_LINE.HR2_58MM;
      receipt += commands.EOL;
      receipt += commands.EOL;
      receipt += commands.EOL;
      receipt += commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_ALIGN_LT;
      //This line here
      receipt += "Total Revenue: "+ revenue;
      receipt += commands.EOL;
      receipt += commands.EOL;
      receipt += commands.EOL;

      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Select your printer',
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Cancel',
            role: 'cancel'
          },
          {
            text: 'Select printer',
            handler: (device) => {
              if(!device){
                this.showToast('Select a printer!');
                return false;
              }
              console.log(device);
              this.print(device, receipt);
            }
          }
        ]
      });

      this.printer.enableBluetooth().then(() => {
        this.printer.searchBluetooth().then(devices => {
          devices.forEach((device) => {
            console.log('Devices: ', JSON.stringify(device));
            alert.addInput({
              name: 'printer',
              value: device.address,
              label: device.name,
              type: 'radio'
            });
          });
          alert.present();
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.showToast('There was an error connecting the printer, please try again!');
        });
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.showToast('Error activating bluetooth, please try again!');
      });
    }
}
```

I want Total Revenue aligned to the left and revenue to the right in the same line so that the receipt can look well aligned when I print it. I have tried what make it work but I have failed to implement it, I need some help. The commands are based on [commands.js](https://github.com/humbertopiaia/escpos-commands-js/blob/master/src/commands.js)

Comment: hi did you found the solution? can you please share?

Comment: Hey I did manage, you can check it here https://github.com/Mathewsmusukuma/ionic-printer-app

Comment: Make use of the commands in the commands provider

Comment: Thanku so much for your response, how can i print image or logo